# How do I delete photos I sent to someone in Hangouts?

Tags: photos, google-hangouts

I would like to have photos removed from hangouts between myself and another person. They are showing up in their albums, not mine. THey are harrasing and sexully explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to delete a message that you sent to someone from their phone. [You can delete it from your phone](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3112001?hl=en) but not theirs.